# I keep getting TypeError: symbol is not a function when i use the await keyword with userEvent.click() when running tests. How do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

**Problem:** I am currently writing tests for my application using jest and react testing library. The specific test I am currently on is that i am trying to test if the page properly navigates to the login page when the user clicks 'already have an account?'.
Also i am using `await userEvent.click` to simulate the user clicking on the button. The issue is that when I type `await userEvent.click(button)` i get the error `TypeError: symbol is not a function`.

**solutions i have tried:** I have tried removing the `await` keyword from `await userEvent.click(button)` but then the test bypasses clicking the button which defeats the purpose ofthe test. I have also tried checking if my versions of userEvent and react testing library are compatible with React 18, which they are.

**What i expect to happen:** I expect that if my code is working well, i should not get the error `TypeError: symbol is not a function` and the button should be clicked, and my test runs.

**Below is my React component code:**

```
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Installation.module.scss';
import WineGlass from '../assets/WineGlass';

function Installation() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  async function installAll() {
    
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5050/install');

      if (!response.ok) {
        //  Throw new error
        console.log('Error installing');
      }

      setLoading(false);
      navigate('/signupPage');
    } catch (err) {
      //  Better error handler here
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  async function portForward() {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5050/portforward');

      if (!response.ok) {
        //  Throw new error
        console.log('Unable to Port-Forward');
      }

      setLoading(false);
      navigate('/loginPage');
    } catch (err) {
      //  Better error handler here
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  let render = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.box}>
          <button className={styles.primary} onClick={installAll}>
            Get Started
          </button>
          <button className={styles.secondary} onClick={portForward}>
            <i>already have an account?</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  if (loading) render = <WineGlass />;

  let added = <></>;
  if (location?.state?.notLogged) {
    added = <div>Forgot to log in stupid</div>;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {added}
      {render}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Installation;
```

**Below is my testing code/ testing suites**

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { getByRole, render, screen} from "@testing-library/react"
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, MemoryRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';


import { server } from '../mocks/server';
import Installation from '../client/src/pages/Installation';

function wrapper({ children }) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {queries: {retry: false}}
  })
  return (
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
}

describe('Navigation', () => {
    test('User is routed to login page when they click on already have an account button', async () => {
      const user = userEvent.setup();
      render (
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element = {<Installation/>}/>
          <Route path='/loginPage' element = {<loginPage/>}/>
        </Routes>,
        { wrapper }
      )
      
      await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'already have an account?'}));
      await screen.findByText('Login')
      

    })
  })
```

**Here is my package.json file as well**

```
  "name": "o",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose",
    "frontend": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot --progress --color",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot --progress --color \" \"NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/server.js\"",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "server": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon ./server/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.14",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router": "^6.11.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "msw": "^1.2.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.84.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  }
}
```